# How radioactive are Heisenberg cubes?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, physical-chemistry, radioactivity

I recently went to a museum that had a $2 \times 2 \times 2$ [Heisenberg cube](http://www.nuclearphysicslab.com/npl/npl-home/history/heisenberg-cube/) on display. I was surprised since it’s about $5 ~\mathrm{lbs}$ of raw uranium and people were coming right up to the plexiglass and hovering around.

What is an estimate for how much radiation they received, in say, $5 ~\mathrm{min}$ at a meter of separation from the source?

Comment: Since those are natural (unenriched) uranium, well, not much at all, particularly behind plexiglass. Remember, U-238 has a very long half life, and neither alphas or betas will get through the plexiglass, leaving only gammas (and neutrons from U-235 spontaneous fission).

Comment: Negligible. One can handle natural uranium with thin gloves and even those are mostly needed to reduce heavy metal contamination. The radiation is not a problem since the alpha and beta radiation can't even penetrate the skin. Having said that, exposure to dust is a real problem because in the lungs serious radiation damage can occur. Machining has to be done very carefully and in glove boxes, but similar problems occur with e.g. beryllium because of chemical toxicity.

Comment: Relying on ChatGPT for anything is a losing proposition. Particularly for radiation physics assessments.

Answer (score 0):

How much radiation you get is not so easy to say. But we can assume that it is very little. The Plexiglas should already provide good shielding and eliminate the danger of $\alpha$-, $\beta$-, $n$ / $p$-, ... radiation. The only thing left would be the $\gamma$ radiation ($\gamma$-rays / $\gamma$-paticles / high energy photons / quanta) to do something to you.

Problems with the calculation would be e.g. the lack of information about how tall you are, which area is exposed, that the thickness of the plexiglass is not given, ...

If we were to believe ChatGTP's unrealistic calculation, we would get:
$$
\begin{align*}
400 ~\frac{\mathrm{\mu Sv}}{\mathrm{hour}} = 400 \cdot \frac{8760}{1000} ~\frac{\mathrm{mSv}}{\mathrm{year}} = 3504 ~\frac{\mathrm{mSv}}{\mathrm{year}} = 3.504 ~\frac{\mathrm{Sv}}{\mathrm{year}}\\
\end{align*}
$$

> [Exposure to $100 ~\frac{\mathrm{mSv}}{\mathrm{year}}$ is the lowest level at which any increase in cancer risk is clearly evident. A cumulative $1000 ~\mathrm{mSv}$ ($1 ~\mathrm{Sv}$) would probably cause a fatal cancer many years later in five out of every $100$ persons exposed to it.](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-how-much-radiation-dangerous-idUSTRE72E79Z20110315)

According to ChatGPT's calculation, if you were constantly exposed to this radiation for a year without a break, you could actually suffer consequences a few years later. So I wouldn't worry about it... Even if ChatGTP calculated the result to high. However, if you were to get radiation all at once, then you would already feel decent symptoms up to the to.

You can find some examples of doses on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sievert#Dose_examples) or [here](https://www.nrc.gov/docs/ML1209/ML120970113.pdf). Note that theste relations are for doses received over very short duration of Ionizing Radiation.